# How to unsubscribe a shared stream

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Basically if a observable is converted from 'cold' to 'hot' by calling `share`, the stream can not be unsubscribe. I never know the rule before! And It introduce some interesting behavior such as

```
const shared = false;
const myObservable = Observable.create(observer => {
    let counter = 0;
    const intervel = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(`${++counter} passed`)
        observer.next(counter)
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
        console.log('myObservable is realised')
        clearInterval(intervel)
    }
})
const start$ = Observable.fromEvent(startButton, 'click');
let interval$
if (shared) {
    interval$ = myObservable.share()
} else {
    interval$ = myObservable
}

const startInterval$ = start$.switchMapTo(interval$)

startInterval$
    .subscribe((v) => {
        console.log('subscribe', v)
    })
```

When `shared` is set to `false`, every time clicking the start button, the counter will start over from 0. If set to `true`, the counter will keep adding on

I create a customized observable by `Observable.create` with `unsubscribe` implemented. And I can see clearly that if `share` is invoked on a stream. `unsubscribe` will never be called

I had followed up several tutorials and use rxjs for quite a while, but uncover the rule first time on my own. Can anyone point out more reference on such rule?

Answer (score 0):

My current understanding:

operators such as `swithMap` and `takeUntil` have to potential to `unsubscribe` a stream internally and start over the stream. It the stream is `shared`, an internal counter of how many downstream pointing to the shared one will be maintained to determine if the potentials should be fulfilled or not